# How do I display vertical 2 images with different resolution?

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I tried this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

top=cv2.imread('top.jpg')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lPL9.jpg

```
bottom=cv2.imread('bottom.jpg')
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gdJg.jpg

```
numpy_vertical= np.vstack((top, bottom))


cv2.imshow('detected', numpy_vertical)
cv2.imwrite('detected.jpg', numpy_vertical)
```

**ValueError**: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 2878 and the array at index 1 has size 5760

Comment: Do you want to stack two images with different resolution on the same image.

Comment: Yes, is it possible somehow?

Comment: Well, you could resize the narrow one to the same width as the wide one. Or resize the wide one to the same width as the narrow one. Or pad the narrow one on the left, or the right, or both, with black, green, blue or any other colour pixels to make its width match the wider one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have taken the following images for example:

**First Image:**

[image]

**Second Image :**

[image]

**Output Image**
[image]

With the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

first = cv2.imread(r"path.... \first.png")
second = cv2.imread(r"path.... \second.png")

h1, w1, c1 = first.shape

h2, w2, c2 = second.shape

h, w= h1+h2, max(w1, w2)

out_image = np.zeros((h,w,c1))

out_image[:h1,:w1, ] = first

out_image[h1:h1+h2,:w2, ] = second

cv2.imwrite(r"path ......out.png", out_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

subplotting in matplotlib can be used too , if you just want to visualize the image

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

first = cv2.imread(r"path.... \first.png")
second = cv2.imread(r"path.... \second.png")

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(first)
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(second)
plt.show()
```